# How to make an Isotope gallery stretch the surrounding container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I have an [Isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co) masonry gallery. It's totally run-of-the-mill, nothing special:

[image]

Now internally, Isotope positions the elements inside the gallery using `position: absolute` (like probably every other masonry library out there):

[image]

The problem is that the `<ul>` surrounding the Isotope elements is *not* resized as the masonry elements are positioned This means that any elements coming after the `<ul>` do not get pushed down, below the masonry gallery, and the gallery elements overlap the stuff beneath it.

This could be fixed by giving the footer (which is just a dumb HTML element right now) some jQuery magic, but I'd like to avoid that.

Is there a way to quickly get the Isotope masonry gallery's height and apply it to the surrounding `<ul>` element, to make the layout work as expected?

Comment: Is it possible to provide some code to reproduce this? It's hard to debug without an MCVE. I'd be happy to update my answer if you do. Also, which version of Isotope does the project use?

Comment: Indeed, it is like you say - the problem solved itself along the way (don't remember what caused it but it was one of the reasons you mention) and then forgot to delete this question!

Comment: Glad it worked out! I don't mind if you delete the question if you think it won't help someone else. Can't stop staring at the shifting grid in the snippet...

Comment: Heh! Turns out I can no longer delete it because it's answered. Oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isotope *does* automatically resize the container for us as demonstrated by the simple example below. It seems possible that a CSS rule is interfering with the library's styles or height calculations. Images that have not yet loaded before initializing the grid may also throw off the height.

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
    $('#grid').append($('<li class="item">').addClass('item' + i % 2));
}

var $grid = $('#grid').isotope({ itemSelector: '.item', layoutMode: 'masonry' });

setInterval(function () {
    if (i++ % 3 == 0) { 
        $grid.isotope({ filter: '*' });
    } else {
        $grid.isotope({ filter: '.item' + i % 2 });
    }
}, 1000);
```

```css
#grid { border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }
.item { margin: 5px; padding: 5px; border: 1px dashed grey; list-style-type: none; }
.item0 { width: 50px; height: 30px; }
.item1 { width: 50px; height: 50px; }
```

```html
<ul id="grid"></ul>
<p>Element below</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>
```